# JUnit how to configure Jackson in MockMvc along with WebApplication context

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

I am using **spring-boot-1.5.10** along with **spring-security-test** & **spring-boot-hateoas** and **JUnit-5**. I have some custom Jackson configuration in my application.MockMvc in unit test not picking those custom Jackson configuration. I would like to know how to inject those configurations in MockMvc along with that I would like to know how to inject custom Jackson module in MockMvc. Please find the below code for reference,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookController.class)
public class BookControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @MockBean
    private BookService bookService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()) //Here i would also like to configure Jackson
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockApiUser(roles = {"API_ADMIN"})
    public void shouldGetBook() throws Exception {
        BookResponse bookResponse = BookResponse.builder()
                .basicInfo(getBasicInfo())
                .extendedInfo(getExtendedInfo())
                .build();
        given(bookService.getBook(apiAuthentication.getApiContext(),"bookUid")).willReturn(bookResponse);
        System.out.println("Input ::"+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bookResponse)); //Here the json string response looks fine.
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/v1/books/bookUid"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType("application/hal+json"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("bookUid").value("bookUid")).andReturn();
        System.out.println("response::"+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()));  //Here the content string is not properly converted by Jackson
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(bookService);
    }
}
```

**JACKSON CONFIGURATION CLASS**

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
  }

}
```

I have googled about this issue but all the links use **StandaloneSetUp** but in my application we are using spring-security so I would like to go with the web application context.

Any help or hint would be appreciable.

Comment: `@Import(TheJacksonConfiguration.class)`?

Comment: Yep, I did it...But it doesn't work...I have already tried it...I have updated the question with the configuration class....

Comment: Along with this configuration, we have autowired this ObjectMapper and added the custom module in many places.

Comment: Ah, but you're constructing your MockMvc by yourself instead of autowiring it into the test. Autowire it instead. BTW, your code is incomplete. What is context? Post a comple example.

Comment: @JBNizet I have updated the question. Sorry for not updating the question properly. Your help would be really appreciable.

Comment: @JBNizet How to configure Jackson in MockMvcBuilders. Is there any way to configure Jackson using  MockMvcBuilders apply method? Like we did for WebApplicationContext?

Comment: I'm not comfortable enough with spring boot tests to answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your messages @JBNizet

Comment: @JBNizet the `@Import` worked perfectly fine for me. You should post it as a own answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I will post below what has been worked for me so far.

Test classes are annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "app.config1.enable=false"
    , "app.xonfig2.enable=false"
})
```

This is helpful when I want to enable or disable a configuration during this test suite. In order for this to work, the Configuration classes must contain:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(
    value = "app.config1.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true
)
public class MyConfig1 {
     .
     .
     .
}
```

Applying this in your case, just enable the Jackson configuration and it should work. If you don't want to enable configurations individually, skip this part and add only the `@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` line.

I hope it helps.